# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name AFTER redirect

Tags: spring

I have a form like this (in a page called add.jsp):

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add" method="post" modelAttribute="addForm">
</form:form>
```

On GET request, i populate modelAttribute:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView add(Map<String, Object> model) {

        model.put("addForm", new AddUserForm());
        return new ModelAndView("add");
    }
```

When i perform the form submitting (a POST request), i have the follow method:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView add(Map<String, Object> model, @Valid AddUserForm form, Errors errors) {

    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        //model.put("addForm", new AddUserForm());
        return new ModelAndView("add");
    }
    ....
}
```

But i get this error: `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'addForm' available as request attribute`

My workaround is to add `model.put("addForm", new AddUserForm());`, the command that i have commented on POST request.... but... where is my error ?

Answer (score 1):

In both case, you are returning the same view (i.e. "add") and this view contains a form with a `modelAttribute="addForm"` therefore the model MUST contains an object named "addForm".

If you don't wan't to populate your model with a new AddUserForm after a POST with errors, you probably should :

- return another view (without the "addForm" model attribute)

or

- reuse the same "addForm": `model.put("addForm", form);`

Comment: I've modified the code returning the same model and works. But in this way i lost the errors variable ? Because i have some validation on my AddForm class (for example @NotBlank(message = "Email is required") on email field) but my add.jsp (where i have <form:errors path="email" cssStyle="color: #ff0000;"/>) do not display the error....

Comment: and what about `model.put("errors", errors);`  then, in the view, display errors when they are defined in the model.

Comment: Looking examples on the net i've see that usually people just return a page without adding the errors in the model (and without returning the model again too)... i dont know why for me all this do not works :(